# materialize css how to check if the destroy function for the Carousel is doing what it is suppose to?

Tags: angular, materialize

I am using materialize CSS to use it is Carousel component and I am trying to reinitialize it because it has a dynamic content but I am not sure if the destroy function is working or not and I don't know how to check if it working properly

why no one answering if my question is vague tell me I will clarify more

```
//these are global variables

      elems;
  instances;

//this is the first initiation of the Carousel
this.elems = document.querySelector('.carousel');
this.instances = M.Carousel.init(this.elems, this.options);
console.log("this is at first initiation");
console.log(this.elems);
console.log(this.instances);

//and in this segment i am trying to reinitiate it
      this.instances.destroy();
      console.log("this is at after using destroy function");
      console.log(this.elems);
      console.log(this.instances);
      this.instances = M.Carousel.init(this.elems, this.options);
      console.log("this is at after reinit function");
      console.log(this.elems);
      console.log(this.instances);
```

and here some screenshots of console logs as asked by @Sean Doherty

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can we see console.log of all your variables every step of the way?

Comment: console logs have been added

Comment: can you try instances[0], and also, I can't see any declaration of your options.

Comment: instances is not an array sry the variable name is a bit confusing but it just store the instance of initiated carousal. and options it is an object that has nothing in it

Comment: Did you have any joy with this? I have the same issue - I don't think the destroy method works properly